# Problema con asincronia en js

Tags: javascript

He estado haciendo una pagina para divertirme un poco con `js` ...

```js
"use strict";
// move status part
let zombieArray = [];
let zombies_container = document.getElementById("cursor_container");
let mouse_in = false;
let mouse_status = document.getElementById("mouse__pos");
let last_zombie_delay = 100;
let last_zombie_id = 0;
let button = document.getElementById("button");

function getRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function randomNumber() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
}
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
    let current_pos = [event.x, event.y];
    mouse_status.innerHTML = `Posicion actual de mouse : ${current_pos[0]}, ${current_pos[1]}`;
});

// click button code
class Zombie {
    constructor(position, delay, id) {
        this.position = position;
        this.id = id;
        this.delay = delay;
        this.ref = document.createElement("div");
        this.ref.setAttribute("id", `zombie_${this.id}`);
        this.ref.style.left = `${this.position[0]}px`;
        this.ref.style.backgroundColor = `#${getRandom(5, 9)}${getRandom(
            5,
            9
        )}${getRandom(5, 9)}`;
        this.ref.style.top = `${this.position[1]}px`;
        this.ref.style.transition = `top ${this.delay}ms, left ${this.delay}ms,transform 0.5s `;

        this.ref.style.transitionTimingFunction =
            "cubic-bezier(0.44, 0.47, 0.73, 0.72)";
        this.position = position;
        this.pos_diff = [randomNumber(), randomNumber()];
    }
    updatePosition(new_position) {
        this.position = [
            new_position[0] - this.pos_diff[0],
            new_position[1] - this.pos_diff[1],
        ];
        this.ref.style.left = `${this.position[0]}px`;
        this.ref.style.top = `${this.position[1]}px`;
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    last_zombie_id++;
    last_zombie_delay += 50;
    let new_zombie = new Zombie([-800, 500], last_zombie_delay, last_zombie_id);
    zombieArray.push(new_zombie);
    zombies_container.appendChild(new_zombie.ref);
});

document.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
    let new_position = [event.x, event.y];
    mouse_in = true;
    zombieArray.forEach(function (cursor) {
        cursor.updatePosition(new_position);
    });
});
```

```css
#button {
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #0f0;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 20px;
    left: 80%;
    top: 5%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #0a0;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#mouse__pos {
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #0f0;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #0a0;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    transform: scale(0, 0);
}

.cursor_container > * {
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #0f0;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50px !important;
    transition-property: left, top, transform;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transform: scale(0.3, 0.3);
}

:root {
    background-color: #222;
}
:root:hover #mouse__pos {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}
#button:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Titulo de la pagina</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="mouse__pos">La posicion del mouse es :</div>
            <div id="button">Generar zombie</div>
            <div class="cursor_container" id="cursor_container"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Ahora mi idea es que los zombies se muevan de manera random cuando el mouse no este en la pantalla y cuando este quieto ... El unico modo que se me ocurre de hacer eso es con un bucle, esto bloquearia el hilo principal y por deduccion el *callback*, con lo cual: ***habra algun modo de resolver esto?***

Comment: Podrías hacer uso de ´setInterval´ https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval para actualizar la posición de los zombies

Comment: @AndresGardiol si, muchas gracias !

Comment: Genial, comenta tu solución como una respuesta para que otros usuarios puedan leerlo. Saludos!